# Loop over files in a directory not working

Tags: bash

Consider this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="$1"

for f in "$DIR"; do
    if [[ "$f" == "*.txt" ]];
    then
        echo "Filename is $f"
fi
done
```

I want to only return files with .txt extension. Calling the script with:

```
./script1 /home/admin/Documents
```

Returns nothing. No error, just blank. What is wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that you expect to loop through all files within the directory you pass. To do that, you need to change your loop:

```
for file in "$1"/*
```

It's worth mentioning that `for` doesn't have any built-in behaviour to enumerate items in a directory, it simply iterates over the list of words that you pass it. The `*`, expanded by the shell, is what results in the loop iterating over a list of files.

Your condition would need modifying too, as the `*` needs to be *outside* of quotes (and the rest doesn't need to be inside them, either):

```
if [[ $f = *.txt ]]
```

But you can avoid the need for the conditional by directly looping through all files ending in `.txt`:

```
for file in "$1"/*.txt
```

You may also want to consider the case where there are no matches, in which case I guess you expect the loop not to run. One way to do that in bash would be:

```
# failing glob expands to nothing, rather than itself
shopt -s nullglob 

for file in "$1"/*.txt
    # ...
done

# unset this behaviour if you don't want it in the rest of the script
shopt -u nullglob
```

Comment: I really had to rub my eyes on `if [[ $f = *.txt ]]`. All these years and tears. ++

Comment: @James what have you been doing differently for all these years?

Comment: Basically about `"${f##.}" = "txt"` and such.