# Loop through files in directory specified using argument

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to loop through files in a directory, where the directory is passed through as an argument. I currently have the following script saved in `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in "$1"/*; do
    echo "File:"
    echo $filename
done
```

And I am running the above using:

```
sh test.sh path/to/loop/over
```

However, the above doesn't output the files at the directory `path/to/loop/over`, it instead outputs:

```
File:
path/to/loop/over/*
```

I'm guessing it's interpreting `path/to/loop/over/*` as a string and not a directory. My expected output is the following:

```
File:
foo.txt
File:
bar.txt
```

Where `foo.txt` and `bar.txt` are files in the `path/to/loop/over/` directory. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46581119/5648954) which suggested to add a `/*` after the `$1`, however, this doesn't seem to help (neither do [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16703720/5648954))

Comment: Kudos for correctly quoting `"$1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would happen if the directory is empty, or misspelled. The shell (in its default configuration) simply doesn't expand a wildcard if it has no matches. (You can control this in Bash with `shopt -s nullglob`; with this option, wildcards which don't match anything are simply removed.)

You can verify this easily for yourself. In a directory with four files,

```sh
sh$ echo *
a       file    or      two

sh$ echo [ot]*
or      two

sh$ echo n*
n*
```

And in Bash,

```sh
bash$ echo n*
n*

bash$ shopt -s nullglob

bash$ echo n*
```

I'm guessing you are confused about how the current working directory affects the resolution of directory names; maybe read [Difference between ./ and ~/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435921/difference-between-and)

Comment: Perhaps a better resource to link to is [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Answer (score 4):

## Iterate over content of directory

### Compatible answer (not only bash)

As this question is tagged [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), there is a *POSIX compatible* way:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in "$1"/* ;do
    [ -f "$file" ] && echo "Process '$file'."
done
```

Will be enough (work with filenames containing spaces):

```
$ myscript.sh /path/to/dir
Process '/path/to/dir/foo'.
Process '/path/to/dir/bar'.
Process '/path/to/dir/foo bar'.
```

This work well by using **any** [posix](/questions/tagged/posix) [shell](/questions/tagged/shell). Tested with `bash`, `ksh`, `dash`, `zsh` and `busybox sh`.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd "$1" || exit 1
for file in * ;do
    [ -f "$file" ] && echo "Process '$file'."
done
```

This version won't print path:

```
$ myscript.sh /path/to/dir
Process 'foo'.
Process 'bar'.
Process 'foo bar'.
```

### Some [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) ways

#### Introduction

I don't like to use `shopt` when not needed... (This change standard
bash behaviours and make script less readables).

There is an elegant way for doing this by using standard bash, without requirement of `shopt`.

Of course, previous answer work fine under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), but. There are some
interresting way for making your script more powerfull, flexible, pretty, detailed...

#### Sample

```
#!/bin/bash

die() { echo >&2 "$0 ERROR: $@";exit 1;}            # Emergency exit function

[ "$1" ] || die "Argument missing."                 # Exit unless argument submitted

[ -d "$1" ] || die "Arg '$1' is not a directory."   # Exit if argument is not dir

cd "$1" || die "Can't access '$1'."                 # Exit unless access dir.

files=(*)                                           # All files names in array $files

[ -f "$files" ] || die "No files found."            # Exit if no files found

for file in "${files[@]}";do                        # foreach file:
    echo Process "$file"                            #   Process file
done
```

#### Explanation: considering *globbing* vs *real files*

When doing:

```
files=(/path/to/dir/*)
```

variable `$files` becomes an *array* containing all files contained under `/path/to/dir/`:

```
declare -p files
declare -a files=([0]="/path/to/dir/bar" [1]="/path/to/dir/baz" [2]="/path/to/dir/foo")
```

But if nothing match glob pattern, star won't be replaced and array become:

```
declare -p files
declare -a files=([0]="/path/to/dir/*")
```

From there. looking for `$files` is like looking for `${files[0]}` ie: *first field in array*. So

```
[ -f "$files" ] || die "No files found."
```

will execute `die` function unless **first field** of array `files` is a **file** (`[ -e "$files" ]` to check for existing **entry**, `[ -d "$files" ]` to check for existing **directory**, ans so on... see `man bash` or `help test`).

But you could do replace this *filesystem* test by some *string based* test, like:

```
[ "$files" = "/path/to/dir/*" ] && die "No files found."
```

or, using array length:

```
((${#files[@]}==1)) && [ "${files##*/}" = "*" ] && die "No files found."
```

#### Dropping paths by using Parameter expansion:

For suppressing *path* from filenames, instead of `cd $path` you could do:

```
targetPath=/path/to/dir
files=($targetPath/*)
[ -f "$files" ] || die "No files found."
```

Then:

```
declare -p files
declare -a files=([0]="/path/to/dir/bar" [1]="/path/to/dir/baz" [2]="/path/to/dir/foo")
```

You could

```
printf 'File: %s\n' ${files[@]#$targetPath/}
File: bar
File: baz
File: foo
```